# Oracle trigger compiling, but not updating

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have this trigger:

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER Trigger_X
before INSERT ON THING
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_NEWTHING    VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  NEW_THING('THING'||:old.CDTHING, V_NEWTHING);
  UPDATE THING 
  SET NUMBERTHING = V_NEWTHING
  WHERE :new.CDTHING = :old.CDTHING;
end;
```

But this code is not working - it does not show errors on compiling, but it won't update THING.

More details: At the line NEW_THING, is the stored procedure. It is returning a V_NEWTHING, that is basically a code to be inserted on the THING. But this code simply does not run, and ORA returns this:

ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "MYDATABASE.NEW_THING", line 33
ORA-06512: at "MYDATABASE.Trigger_X", line 4

How can i solve this problem? I am fairly new to Oracle.

Comment: You must remove COMMIT from `NEW_THING` procedure. ALternatively don't call the procedure from the trigger. Oracle doesn't permit COMMIT inside triggers.

Comment: It worked, but now, it won't save. Am i messing with these old: and news? @kordirko ?

Comment: If you execute any DML statement: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, then you must perform COMMIT to save changes (or ROLLBACK to undo changes). The transaction (client, application) that executes INSERT must do COMMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a row-level trigger so you don't want to do `DML` against the `THING` table.  Just assign the `:new.numberting` column

```
new_thing( 'THING' || :old.cdthing, v_newthing );
:new.numberthing := v_newthing'
```

That assumes, of course, that the goal of your `UPDATE` statement is to modify the data in the row that is being inserted.  If `cdthing` is not the primary key, you've got a bigger problem.